# Upload buttons missing because of broken Flex uploader?

Tags: magento-1.7, image-upload

I know this has been discussed several times, but I could not find any information on my problem. I guess its due to patch 8788. This is an older **1.7.0.2** store and whenever I open a product to upload images the buttons are missing.

I get JavaScript errors so I checked the source using the dev tools in Chrome. In the srouce it looks like this:

```
 = new Flex.Uploader('id_866e99d3098a9212b06b94f068f22b75_Uploader', '', );
```

The source in uploader.phtml looks like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getJsObjectName() ?> = new Flex.Uploader('<?php echo $this->getHtmlId() ?>', '<?php echo $this->getUploaderUrl('media/uploader.swf') ?>', <?php echo $this->getConfigJson() ?>);
```

So as it seems `$this->getJsObjectName()` and the other similiar calls return nothing. Any ideas why and how to fix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Magento 1.7.x 
[this article solved my problem](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Version-Upgrades/Product-Image-Uploader-broken-in-1-9-3/m-p/50670#M1917)

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I am not using the CreareSEO Extension by the way.

Comment: I mean that I have done changes like here: https://github.com/adampmoss/CreareSEO/pull/78/files#diff-0496ceab82e51dcadccb8a23074fbe17L97

Answer (score 0):

These buttons are coming from flash.So check your media folder on following location

design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media

if there is no media folder then copy from fresh magento

This will solve your problem :) if not Try solution from below links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022532/image-upload-buttons-are-missing-in-magento-in-back-end

Comment: I found that, too, but I want to fix the problem without that please :)

Comment: i have updated my answer please check it

Comment: Yeah, but the folders and the correct content are there, cache cleared as well.

Comment: **Please check to see if the following files are in their proper places:**

`/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/editor.swf
/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf
/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media/uploader.phtml
/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media/editor.phtml`